# PHP doesnt have permission to change file name

Tags: php, apache

I want to change file name in subdirectory under `/usr/local/MyFolder/overlay.png` to `overlay2.png` with php, but php raises Permission below Error:

> ( [type] => 2 [message] => rename(/usr/local/MyFolder/content/overlay.png,/usr/local/MyFolder/overlay2.png): Permission denied [file] => /var/www/html/2.php [line] => 6 )

How to solve it?

Comment: Try changing thy rights of your script with the chmod() function.

Answer (score -3):

RUn the following command from Terminal:

You can get to the terminal by Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard

Run the following code:

```
sudo chmod 777 "/usr/local/MyFolder/"


sudo chmod 777 "/usr/local/MyFolder/content/"
```

Now your script should have permissions to access those folders

Mind you, doing these gives permission to everyone and every programs to access and modify things in the folders above